# Correctly treating DST shift with momentJS

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic2, momentjs, localnotification

I've came across something that I thought it was right, but now taking a closer look something is clearly wrong.

I'm on a project of a pill reminder app where someone can set notifications to remind him/her of taking pills in the correct time. There're medicines which a person can take for the rest of his life. And in that case I don't set alerts for years, I set for 3 months max and, when he takes one and mark it as done, I set another alert for 3 months later starting on that date/time.

This app will be released only in Brazil and we have Daylight Saving Time here. When it shifts to DST time the clocks must be adjusted to -1 hour after midnight, when going off DST it gains 1 hour.

For this project I'm using Firebase, Ionic 2, the LocalNotification Plugin and Moment JS.

I have to make a story of the user because other user can see if he's taking it correctly, so I use Moment JS to manipulate the datetime and save the notification and create a node for that user in firebase with UNIX time.

**LET'S FINALLY GO TO THE PROBLEM.**

When saving a date I check if this date is DST, if it is I add +3 hours to it, if it's not I add +2. I need to add this because when I wrap the isoString in the `Moment()` function it gives me -3 hours or -2 hours (Haven't searched for this, but I think Moment uses USA time).

This works fine if I'm saving dates inside DST times if I'm in DST time, if in some case I'm not on DST and save a notification for a DST time day it saves with +2 hours.

**AN EXAMPLE**

The DST time will shift to `in DST` on October 15. If I need to save 30 notifications, one per day everyday as 12AM, starting at October 1 up to October 30. From day 1 to day 15 the dates will be right, from day 16 to 30 they'll be with +2 hours.

Here's the basic code I use:

```
// THIS'LL SET MY DATEPICKER TO THE DATE/HOUR I'M IN.
minDate: any = Moment().isDST ? Moment().subtract(3, 'h').toDate().toISOString() : Moment().subtract(2, 'h').toDate().toISOString();

// THIS'LL CONVERT THE SELECTED DATE TO A UNIX TIME IN WHICH I'LL USE TO SAVE THE NOTIFICATION AND THE MEDICATION DATA ON FIREBASE
unixConverted = Moment(this.minDate).isDST ? Moment(this.minDate).add(3, 'h').unix() : Moment(this.minDate).add(2, 'h').unix();
```

What is strange is that using `Moment().unix()` alone it give me the right time I'm in, if I use `Moment(this.minDate).unix()` it gives me -2 or -3 hours of the hour I selected.

So if it's in DST (in which I've set my clock to -1 hour) I add 3, if not I add 2.

- So how is the proper way to manipulate this DST shift?
- Is there a better way to do this than using DST?
- Am I right using this logic or is this much more complex than what I think?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i've found a better way without using `.isDST()` method.

Simple use `Moment().add(Moment().utcOffset(), 'm')`, this'll get the current moment time and add the offset in minutes.

The `.add()` and `.subract()` methods makes Moment return the UTC time.

The `utcOffset()` returns a positive or negative number of minutes (representing hours) from UTC, like -60 or 180. So i'll get the correct respecting the time shift.

Worked like a charm for me.